# Store the signing key using Data Protection API

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, jwt, dpapi

I am working on .Net Core Web API, in which we are using Jwt Token for authorizing web requests. Below is the code to generate token and configure it in the startup.

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
{
    options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
    options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters
    {
        ValidateAudience = false,
        ValidateIssuer = false,
        ValidateIssuerSigningKey = true,
        IssuerSigningKey = new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(Configuration["Security:Key"])),
        ValidateLifetime = true,
        ClockSkew = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5)
    };
});
```

Generate Token :

```
private string GenerateToken(string username)
{
    var claims = new[]
    {
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Name, username),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Nbf, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
        new Claim(JwtRegisteredClaimNames.Exp, new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.Now.AddDays(1)).ToUnixTimeSeconds().ToString()),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Role, "PB"),
        new Claim(ClaimTypes.Version, _configuration["Version"]),
    };

    var token = new JwtSecurityToken(
        new JwtHeader(new SigningCredentials(
            new SymmetricSecurityKey(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(_configuration["Security:Key"])),
            SecurityAlgorithms.HmacSha256)),
        new JwtPayload(claims));

    return new JwtSecurityTokenHandler().WriteToken(token);
}
```

This is working as expected. Recently we received a suggestion that instead of using `_configuration["Security:Key"]` hardcoded secret key to sign the token, make use of [Data Protection API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/using-data-protection?view=aspnetcore-3.1). After going through the documentation, I have the following questions:

- How to combine JWT Token Signing with Data Protection API?
- Do I have to use keys from DPAPI to sign the token or Use DPAPI's protect and unprotect method to do send the encrypted token in response?
- I am not able to find any way to encrypt the token using DPAPI. Is it even possible?
- Is it good practise to extract the master key/ or any key from DPAPI to do the token signing?

Any Suggestions?

Our goal is to get rid of the configuration based secret key and make use of DPAPI.

**Edit:**

As mentioned by @jps in the comment section, in this case, we have to store the singing the key using DPAPI.

**Updated Question:**

How do I achieve the same? Any code samples would be helpful.

Comment: I think, the person who suggested this, really didn't mean anything else than just to make use of Data Protection API to **store the signing key**,instead of using `_configuration["Security:Key"].`. Beside that, `dpapi` has really nothing to do with signing or encrypting the JWT. It's just a safe storage for the key.

Comment: Do you have any example on how to store signing key in dpapi?

Comment: see if [this article from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/data-protection/implementation/key-encryption-at-rest?view=aspnetcore-3.1) helps

Comment: Consider signing it with a certificate instead, that way you just look at the local cert store and you can sign using that. No need to "secret" keys or anything. security through internal platform (windows or linux user management for the webserver process)

Comment: @VisualBean could you please be more specific? It's not clear how a certificate shouldn't be secret in this case. Also you need to store it somewhere still. Looks like IKeyManager doesn't allow this.

Comment: It is ofcourse also a secret in the same respect that a key would be, but it is safeguarded by built-in mechanisms instead of the data-protection api and custom logic. After it is installed, its just a matter of authorizing access to the store and it will work.
You can consider keeping the certificate in something like azure keyvault as an alternative.

Comment: @Shaggy did you have a chance to find a solution?

Comment: @deeptowncitizen Not yet.